# What is the purpose of these `NUL` characters?

Tags: text-formatting, syntax, typography

This is purely out of academic curiosity, but I’ve often found files on both Windows (Windows 10 Pro; 64bit) as well as Android that are *not* obfuscated, but contain a bunch of `NUL` characters between each actual relevant character, making it difficult to read as-is on Windows (on Android at least, the explorer application I use [— X-plore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore&hl=en_US) — seems to auto-remove when launching as text in edit mode). Here's an example:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That's a binary file ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a binary file which contains characters outside the set of [printable ASCII characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Because these characters are "*not printable*", Notepad++ displays them as a descriptive block. You'll likely see others, as shown below. Here you see all of the values from binary 0 / `0x00` to 255 / `0xFF` (which is the largest value that can be stored in a single byte).

[image: all binary values from 0 to 255 displayed by notepad++]

The values shown on lines 1, 2 and 3 are typically referred to as "*Control Characters*", and are used to influence the terminal, cursor placement, etc... a `NUL` has the value 0 / `0x00`. The `BS` control character is "*Backspace*", and instructs the application to remove one character and move the cursor back one space. Worthy of note are the "*missing*" or invisible characters between `BS` and `VT`... in here are the "*Horizontal Tab*" and "*Line Feed*" characters - the former is fairly self explanatory, and the latter will makes the text flow on to the next line.

On lines 4 and 5 you can see the entire set of printable ASCII characters. A space () has the binary values 32 / `0x20`, an exclaimation point has the values 33 / `0x21`, etc... The funny square box on the end of line 5 is the `DEL` control character - 127 / `0x7F`.

All values including and above 128 are either "*Extended ASCII*", or also non-printable, and these are displayed from line 6 onwards as their raw value - e.g: `x80`. There isn't a good way to determine how to interpret these - some DOS applications used some of these characters to produce [frames around "*windows*", boxes or areas on the terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character).

[image: mc screenshot]

For more information, see the "*[Character Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_groups)*" section of the wiki page.

Viewing the same file as above in a "*[Hex Editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor)*", you will typically see the raw binary values alongside the ASCII representation.

[image: hex editor]

---

When the file contains data other than plain text (e.g: it's an application, or other binary file), you'll see a lot of non-print characters, because they were never intended for human consumption... In such files, the data is laid out in binary, usually following a strict structure or format. In some cases the data represents large numbers (by concatenating a number of bytes together), in other cases they might represent "*[machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code)*" or raw instructions that are presented directly to a processor.

You *might* be able to see strings inside such binary files, but this is more "*by accident*" than on purpose - the application itself has to know what to print to the screen when you see a message, and this will be that.

There are a couple of common ways that strings are encoded in binary files.

#### 1. C String

This format makes use of 8-bit characters, and terminates the string with a `NUL` character. The string is immediately visible in the file, as shown below - note the terminating `NUL`.

[image: C String example]

#### 2. [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)

This format makes use of 16-bit characters (i.e: two bytes concatenated), and can represent a portion of the code points described by [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). Here, you see that the string is somewhat visible, if you read between the `NUL` characters... This format is very common in applications that target Windows.

Can you see the string `Logical Disks` on the second line?

[image: UTF-16 example]

---

Binary files can also store other resources inside them - for example images, sounds, XML, JSON, Archives, etc... the application can then extract the resources to disk at runtime if necessary, or may often process them directly from memory.

It's often possible to extract these resources using tools in an automated fashion, but in some cases the file is not designed to an open / common standard, and some manual intervention is required.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a file to store data, you can store a series of bytes. 1 byte is any number between 0 and 255. In many fileformats, it is enough to use any number between 0 and 255 to store data.

But as systems get more complex and advanced, developers sometimes need to store numbers that are far greater than 255. 2 bytes = 256*256 = 65535, 4 bytes = 256*256*256*256 = 4294967296. So by combining 4 bytes, one can store values from 0 to 4294967295.

You can even combine 8 or more bytes to form a number which often happens in 64-bit applications where you need 64 bits (8x8 bytes).

Because numbers stored are often low, most of the bytes are 0, aka NUL. So in a file, you see a lot of NUL because it are all low values in 64-bit constructions.

Why would one not optimize the file? Because most programmers use functions that store the data for them, and they keep every scenario in mind, including storing big numbers.

Answer (score 1):

That is a very popular convention to store strings: usually programs will know the location of the beginning of the string and will know that the string has ended because the `NUL` (or `NULL` or `\0`) character is found.

If you compare this to CSV, you can think it as the coma separating each column. Except that here it's a special character that cannot be typed nor printed and has no other use than delimiting string endings.

You may think that this is flimsy and it's indeed a cause for countless security issues. But still up to today, many strings are still delimited this way.

However in your screenshot this might have a different meaning, specific to the application you're using. Overall, binary data is not made to be read with a text editor.

Comment: Is it not meant to be human-readable through text editors? Because there often are portions that are, e.g., `manifests.xml` have the intent flags stored in human-readble block of text.

Comment: `manifests.xml` is readable by humans while other files are not. There is many many kinds of files. The general use of the `NUL` character is what I described above, it's however impossible to give you an answer covering all file types.

Comment: @user1686 Ah, i see, that explains the two different answers.  In that case, i believe from the inquirer's perspective it's reasonable to presume they may not be aware of such a distinction, but from the meta standpoint how should I handle the answer marking since both were technically relevant?